# I have problem with docerize my app nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15.9.0-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
# Add a work directory
WORKDIR /
# Cache and Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
# Copy app files
COPY . .
# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Bundle static assets with nginx
FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine as production
ENV NODE_ENV production
# Copy built assets from builder
COPY --from=build /build /usr/share/nginx/html
# Add your nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Expose port
EXPOSE 80
# Start nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When i try run "docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build" in Terminal I get an error

> invalid from flag value builder: pull access denied for builder, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: You did not name your build container, but referred to it by name. just change to `FROM node:15.9.0-alpine as build`

Comment: It's works thanks guy ;)